# how to get Mysql COUNT within subquery

Tags: mysql

here i have a table named as test2. i need to get the below output from a single mysql query.i have tried it using a subquery but i was fail. kindly help me to sort this.

pending status- 154

completed status - 159

[image]

required output

[image]

query that i have tried

```
SELECT
    (
        test2.doc_no,
        SELECT
            (
                Count(test2.esn) AS pending_quantity,
                test2.doc_no
            FROM
                test2
            WHERE
                test2.sttus = 154
            GROUP BY
                test2.doc_no
            ),
            SELECT
                (
                    Count(test2.esn) AS completed_quantity,
                    test2.doc_no
                FROM
                    test2
                WHERE
                    test2.sttus = 159
                GROUP BY
                    test2.doc_no
                )
    )
```

Comment: You could use some group by. I post you an answer as soon as I can

Comment: `SELECT test2.doc_no,sum(CASE WHEN status=154 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as pending,sum(CASE WHEN status=159 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as completed from test2 GROUP by doc_no`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT doc_no,
SUM(STATUS=154) AS pending_quantity,
SUM(STATUS=159) AS completed_quantity
FROM 
test2 GROUP BY doc_no
```

Try above query.